# Code formatting in comments discards whitespace

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed by writing a comment that multiple spaces are replaced by a single space inside a code block. The [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86323/how-do-you-add-positional-parameters) has since been migrated to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447397/how-do-you-add-positional-parameters).

I worked around it by replacing spaces with underscores, but that looks awkward at least.

Put aside that comments are not for code, is that a known behaviour? (And if so, what is the correct way to handle that situation?)

Comment: `This           is         confirmed          !` http://i.imgur.com/gPb2Y.png

Comment: So many years and not an answer...